# How do I test a promise using Mocha? Getting "ReferenceError: <promise_name> is not a function"

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js

I've written a promise that makes a call and checks the response code. I want to test this using node. I keep getting "TypeError: index.GeneratePromise is not a function" and I can't figure out whats wrong.

I've tried wrapping the promise in another function, and calling that from the test file. This doesn't wait for the promise response, and the returned value is "undefined". I've tried multiple forms of promises, async/await etc. which also haven't worked.

My test

```
var assert = require('assert');
var index = require('../index');
describe('Basic Mocha String Test', function () {

  it('promise', function () {
    index.GeneratePromise().then(function(value) {
      console.log("promise value: ", value);
      assert.equal(value, 200);
    });
  });
});
```

My promise

```
exports.GeneratePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  https.get('https://www.google.com/', (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
      console.log('status code: ', resp.statusCode)
      resolve(resp.statusCode);
    });
  }).on("error", (err) => {
    reject(err);
  });
});
```

I'm hoping to have at least some value, not "undefined" returned. It's an issue of not waiting for my promise in the test file.

Comment: `it()` will give you a callback that you can use to signal that you are done.  However, the error you are getting doesn't match the problem description.  Are you sure you're importing correctly?  Once you fix your imports, you should try `it("blah", done => { MyPromise.then(done);})`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm importing correctly. I can create a test function next to GeneratePromise, which is not a promise. eg exports.TestFunction = function() {...} and call the same way: const code = index.TestFunction() and that runs fine.

Comment: Oh, remove the `()` from the test.  You are trying to call a primitive as though it were a function.  Just do `index.GeneratePromise.then(...)`.  You still need the callback format mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting an actual Promise, not a function that creates a Promise.  Because of that, you shouldn't use the `()`.  Additionally, `it()` can provide you with a callback to tell mocha your test is done.  See [mochas async docs](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).  Try this:

```js
var assert = require('assert');
var index = require('../index');
describe('Basic Mocha String Test', function () {
  it('promise', function (done) {
  //index.GeneratePromise().then(function(value) {
    index.GeneratePromise.then(function(value) { // Notice there is no ()
      console.log("promise value: ", value);
      assert.equal(value, 200);
      done(); // This tells mocha your test is done
    });
  });
});
```